# Usage of static variables in Java

Tags: java

I knew that Static variables are created and initialized only one time I.e when the class is loaded and not per object.

In the code given below what I am trying to do is: I declared an int variable "a" as static in class A and assigned it a value of 5. When the main is executed I changed its value to 6 and made the program to loop infinitely. So currently "a" value is 6.

Now what I tried to do is I tried to access this variable from other class class B when class A is still looping and I expected that 6 should be printed when I ran class B (because by the time I ran class B "a" value is changed to 6) but surprisingly it still gave me 5.

Why is this happening even though I declared "a" as static? Unable to figure out what's wrong with this approach.

```
class A{
    static int a=5;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(A.a+"");
        a=6;
        while(true){
        }
    }
}

class B{    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(A.a+"");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are running two separate programs via `A.main` and `B.main`. You'd have to use threads within the same process to demonstrate what you expect to see.

Comment: Or better -- a static initializer block.

Comment: I dont think threads are necessary.  In B;  `pubic static void main ( String [ ] args ) { A . main ( args ) ; System . out . println ( A . a + "" ) ; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are running two different JVM processes. What you should be doing is running each of your "main" methods in its own thread. This way they share (and therefore can modify) the same memory. Here is your example modified to use threads:

```
public class Main{
    public static int v = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        new Thread(new A()).start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        new Thread(new B()).start();
    }
}

class A implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println(Main.v);
        Main.v = 6;
    }
}

class B implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println(Main.v);
    }
}
```

Side note: While this example does demonstrate what is expected from the question, there is still a lot of things wrong in terms of writing a *correct* Java program that uses multiple threads. Do your reasearch.

Comment: ya u r right i tried to load the two programs in different processes that's the mistake. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Your are running two java processes and two programs. The second classloader loads `class A` and sets its static variable to 5 but there is no call in `class B` to invoke that static main() method defined in `class A` that increments it to 6.

Comment: ya u r right i tried to load the two programs in different processes that's the mistake. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You never really run the main loop in A.

Just make a method to change the value.

Comment: i ran Class A first so "a" value should be changed to 6. After this, while A is struck in a while loop i tried to access "a" in class B i got 5 as answer.

Comment: Where do you run "A" first? You would have to run those two in the same class, to get what you want. They are still two separate objects right now, that has nothing to do with each other. So you are just accessing the variable, not really changing it before you access it with B.

Comment: ya u r right i tried to load the two programs in different processes that's the mistake. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

That is because the main method of A is never invoked.