# Android custom view button with custom attribute is referencing the same object

Tags: java, android, android-button, android-custom-view

I have a custom `button` that extends `View`. In the constructor I am setting a member variable to hold a custom attribute set in the XML definition. At the moment there are 5 of these buttons defined in the XML each with a different int attached to represent a stage.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mycompany.stagedApp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
style="@style/stepFooter">

<com.mycompany.stagedApp.StepButtonView
    android:text="@string/step_one_icon"
    style="@style/numberedIcon"
    android:id="@+id/step_one_button"
    custom:stepNumber="1"
    android:background="@drawable/circle" />
<com.mycompany.stagedApp.StepButtonView
    android:text="@string/step_two_icon"
    style="@style/numberedIcon"
    android:id="@+id/step_two_button"
    custom:stepNumber="2"
    android:background="@drawable/circle" />
<com.mycompany.stagedApp.StepButtonView
    android:text="@string/step_three_icon"
    style="@style/numberedIcon"
    android:id="@+id/step_three_button"
    custom:stepNumber="3"
    android:background="@drawable/circle" />
<com.mycompany.stagedApp.StepButtonView
    android:text="@string/step_four_icon"
    style="@style/numberedIcon"
    android:id="@+id/step_four_button"
    custom:stepNumber="4"
    android:background="@drawable/circle" />
<com.mycompany.stagedApp.StepButtonView
    android:text="@string/step_five_icon"
    style="@style/numberedIcon"
    android:id="@+id/step_five_button"
    custom:stepNumber="5"
    android:background="@drawable/circle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the `StepButtonView.java` I have:

```
class StepButtonView extends View {

  private static int stepNumber;

  public StepButtonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.custom_values);
    stepNumber = ta.getInt(R.styleable.custom_values_stepNumber, 0);

    // This log correctly displays the numbers 1 - 5
    Log.d("StepFromCustom in constructor", String.format("%d",StepButtonView.stepNumber));

    this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("Step", String.format("%d", view.getId()));
            // This log only displays the last number 5
            Log.d("StepFromCustom", String.format("%d",StepButtonView.stepNumber));
        }
    });
  }
}
```

When the `activity` starts and each button is constructed the numbers 1 -5 are logged. However on click the number logged is always 5, the last `stepNumber`. In the `onClick listener` it lists a different ID value but the same `stepNumber` so my initial thought that it was referring to the same object must be incorrect.

Could anyone explain what's going on, and why, as I think this is a misunderstanding with the language which I obviously need to clear up.

Comment: don't use stepNumber as static member

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of static variables in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689934/usage-of-static-variables-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your `stepNumber` is `static`. That means it's a class variable, thus it will remain 5, as it is the last value which is set (constructor of you last `Button`). Removing it will solve the problem.

Let's run through the application:

- First constructor: `stepNumber` is 1.
- Second constructor: `stepNumber` is 2.
- Third constructor: `stepNumber` is 3.
- Fourth constructor: `stepNumber` is 4.
- Fifth constructor: `stepNumber` is 5.

After this it is not set anymore, so it will remain 5. So:

- every `onClick` after that: `Log.d()` will output 5

Edit: seeing your comment, you probably mean a `final` attribute, which cannot be modified and only be set in the constructor. Seeing that you already set it in your constructor, it's perfectly fine to add that to your attribute, making it:

```
private final int stepNumber;
```

Edit2: `static` members belong to the class instead of a specific instance.

It means that **only one instance of a `static` field exists** even if you create a million instances of the class or you don't create any. It will be shared by all instances.

Comment: OK. I thought that each object that is created would have its own static member variable, which held a distinct value assigned in construction. I think you are saying that the static keyword is creating a single instance of the variable, not 5 different ones contained in their own scope?

Comment: Thank you. For completeness are you able to explain why it works this way? Specifically, if you create 5 different objects and set static variables in each, why are they then the same? Static class variables are same in all instances?

Comment: @voncox `static` variables are not bound to objects, but to classes. That's why you call normal methods like this: `myObjectInstance.getValue()` (you dont see `myObjectInstance.myValue` that often, because object attributes are mostly `private/protected`) and `static` methods/variables like this: `MyClass.MYCLASSVARIABLE`; So you dont need any instances of your class to set the `static` class variable.